# MySQL - selecting random row from large table

Tags: php, mysql, random

I apologise if this topic has been done to the death but I'm struggling with selecting a random row from a large MySQL table. It's a table named `photos` and its primary key is `PhotoID`. At the moment its ID's range from ~1500 (due to rows being created in testing then deleted) to ~12000, with some gaps, and I expect it will grow much larger yet.

While it's been relatively small I've been using:

```
 SELECT PhotoID FROM photos
```

...into a PHP array `$All_IDs`, then in PHP:

```
 $RandomID = $All_IDs[mt_rand(0,count($All_IDs)-1)]
```

then:

```
 SELECT /* other columns */ FROM photos WHERE PhotoID = $RandomID
```

This works great, I get a good range of random photos when I repeat it. However I don't think it's going to work out very efficient to load the entire `PhotoID` column to select one random ID, then another query to get that record, especially if I'm going to be selecting several. Likewise I'd rather not select the entire table (all columns) into an array just to pick out one. With the help of a few other StackOverflow answers I came up with the following:

```
SELECT MIN(PhotoID) INTO @MinID FROM photos;
SELECT MAX(PhotoID) INTO @MaxID FROM photos;
SELECT PhotoID,/* other columns */ FROM photos WHERE PhotoID >= (@MinID + RAND() * (@MaxID - @MinID)) ORDER BY PhotoID LIMIT 0,1
```

I thought this would work but I'm finding repeating this query several times is only giving me a short spread of ID's, in the 1500 - 1700 range, when, as above, the ID's currently go towards 12,000. I can't understand why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are seeing that small range of values because `RAND()` (in the `WHERE` clause) is being evaluated for *every* row in the table. And it's much more likely that PhotoID on the row is going to be greater than a lower value returned by the expression on the right side. So the query is returning a set  that is more weighted to the lower PhotoID values. With the ORDER BY, you're going to get the lowest.

To get a more random distribution, you'd need to have RAND() evaluated just *one* time. Also, I'd prefer not to execute multiple queries (three separate SELECT statements) when I can get the work done in a single statement, and without user-defined variables.

To implement the algorithm it looks like you are attempting to achieve, I'd approach it something like this:

```
  SELECT t.photoid 
       , ...
    FROM photos t
    JOIN ( SELECT m.min_id + RAND() * (max_id - min_id) AS _rand
             FROM ( SELECT MIN(p.photoid) AS min_id
                         , MAX(p.photoid) AS max_id
                      FROM photos p
                   ) m
         ) r
      ON r._rand <= t.photoid
   ORDER BY t.photoid
   LIMIT 1
```

In MySQL, the inline views (*derived tables* in the MySQL parlance) will be materialized first, before the outer query. Since `m` returns a single row, the RAND() function in `r` will be evaluated only one time. And then the single value from the expression will be used in the outer query.

Comment: That's ideal, thanks ... I avoided `ORDER BY RAND()` as I knew `RAND()` would be called for every row, but I thought it would only be called once if it was part of the `WHERE` clause. I'd never thought of using `JOIN` that way either.

Comment: NOTE:  this approach isn't necessarily the best approach to returning a random row from a set. I attempted to explain the reason for the behavior observed with the original query, and an example of implementing what looks to be the intended design of the original query.  (Using JOIN in this case works because the inline view `r` will return a single row.) If there's some reason you need to use multiple statements, as in the original, move the RAND() operation out to a separate statement, and pass a *single* static value into the actual query. Which is what the query in this answer is doing.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select * from photos order by rand() limit 1;
```

Comment: Note that MySQL will evaluate the RAND() function for *every* row in the table. And then the resulting set will require a "Using filesort" operation to identify the row that has the lowest value of RAND(). This approach tends not to scale well for large sets.